# Cant install javac properly

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

i'm really new to NativeScript, i'm trying to install it properly, but I 've got an issue with javac , displayed with 'tns doctor'  :
**Javac version 14 is not supported. You have to install at least 1.8.0 and below 13.0.0.**

and I ve already download and install JDK 8 manually but it does'nt detect it.
I've tried with "Configure for Local Guide" and I've got another issue like that :
**Error: Cask 'adoptopenjdk8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
WARNING: Open JDK 8 not installed**
Any idea ? Thanks

I'm runnning on IOS Catalina

Answer (score 0):

try uninstalling your current version of java by
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml
and then installing java 8.

and as a newbee it would be great if you set up android studio first for emulator purposes..